# Get Parent Entity based on Child Entity using Hibernate Filter

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate

I have two tables one is PRODUCT and associated table(PRODUCT_COUNTRY_MAPPING) which contain the list of country in which this product is sellable.
There is one to Many relation in Product for PRODUCT_COUNTRY_MAPPING

*For ex.

1. IPhone 14 Pro max is allowed to sell in USA and UAE
2. Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra is allowed to sell in UAE and IND

My requirement is to fetch sellable Product based on the selected country on the UI i.e. I have to show the sellable product available for that country.
For ex.

1. User selected USA as country on UI then User should only see **IPhone 14 Pro max** as this is the only product we have for USA.
2. if User selected UAE as country then we have to show **IPhone 14 Pro max** and **Samsung Galaxy S22 Ultra** as these two product is available for UAE.

**I was trying to do this using Hibernate Filter.**

But I couldn't found how to apply a Hibernate Filter on the Product Entity so that it will check a condition on Child Entity(PRODUCT_COUNTRY_MAPPING) and return the Parent Entity.

Is it possible to use Hibernate Filter the Parent Entity based on child entity?